# Using VBA how do I load an API DataSet into Excel from an HTTP GET function?

Tags: excel, vba, api, web-scraping, dataset

I'm trying to load the DataSet output from an API call directly into a cell range on my worksheet. Specifically I just need TASK_ID, TASK_NUMBER, TASK_RESUME, and TASK_GROUP_NAME. They've provided some [.NET code examples here](http://api.aceproject.com/explorer/?fct=gettasks) for the API function I'm  utilizing, but the code doesn't translate directly into VBA.

I've successfully parsed and utilized JSON for prior functions, but for this task I need to actually output the response back into Excel. I have the option of formatting the HTTP response as XML, RecordSet, DataSet, or JSON. As this is also a bit of a learning opportunity for me I'd like to learn and utilize DataSet for this function, but if XML makes more sense then I'll trust your judgement, but ideally I'd like to be able to use either.

I've commented out the relevant .NET code I copied from the API example, the top portion was what I found from an XML tutorial.

```
Private URL As String
Sub Query_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Generator")

URL = Worksheets("API").Range("B7")
Dim strResp As String: strResp = GetHTTP(ByVal URL)
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(strResp) Then
    MsgBox "Load Error"
End If

'    Dim dsOutput As DataSet: dsOutput = Deserialize(Of DataSet)(strXML)
'            If dsOutput IsNot Nothing AndAlso dsOutput.Tables.Count > 0 Then
'                If dsOutput.Tables.Contains("dtAPIErrors") Then
'                    Throw New Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", _
'                                                      dsOutput.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ErrorNumber").ToString, _
'                                                      dsOutput.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ErrorDescription").ToString))
'                End If
'            End If

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

End Sub
Private Function GetHTTP(ByVal URL As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        GetHTTP = .ResponseText
    End With

End Function

'Private Function Deserialize(Of T)( ByVal strXML As String) As T
'        Dim objet As T = Nothing
'        Dim objType As Type = GetType(T)
'        Try
'            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strXML) Then
'                Dim objSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objType)
'                Dim objText As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
'                Dim objXmlReader As New System.IO.StringReader(strXML)
'                objet = DirectCast(objSerializer.Deserialize(objXmlReader), T)
'                objXmlReader.Close()
'            End If
'            Return objet
'        Catch ex As Exception
'            Throw
'        Finally
'            If objet IsNot Nothing Then objet = Nothing
'        End Try
'End Function
```

I'd like to load everything in starting at Row 9, with the Task ID into Column A, Task # into Column B, Task Resume (AKA Task Name) into Column C, and Task Group into Column D. If I can get a working example for just 1 of the DataSet records I'm sure I'll be able to replicate it for the others.

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="dsOutput">
<xs:element name="dsOutput" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="dtOutput" msdata:CaseSensitive="False" msdata:Locale="en-US">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="TASK_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_NUMBER" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_RESUME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_TASK_MODIFIED" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="IS_ASSIGNED_OR_REVIEWER" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ASSIGNED" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="REVIEWER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ASSIGNED_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="REVIEWER_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PROJECT_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PROJECT_NUMBER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PROJECT_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PROJECT_TYPE_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="COMPANY_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_GROUP_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_GROUP_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_GROUP_MYORDER" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_TYPE_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_TYPE_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_TYPE_MYORDER" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_STATUS_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_STATUS_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_STATUS_MYORDER" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED_LOGICAL_SORT" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_PRIORITY_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_PRIORITY_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_PRIORITY_MYORDER" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="USER_CREATOR_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="USERNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="FIRST_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="LAST_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_DESC_CREATOR" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_DESC_CREATOR_PLAIN" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ESTIMATED_TIME" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_EXPECTED_START_TASK" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_EXPECTED_END_TASK" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_TASK_CREATED" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="POURCENTAGE_DONE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ACTUAL_HOURS" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ACTUAL_PERCENT_DONE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DOCUMENT_COUNT" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ACTUAL_START_DATE" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ACTUAL_END_DATE" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DIVIDE_HOURS" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="WEEKEND_ALLOWED" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UPDATE_USER_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UPDATE_USERNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UPDATE_FIRST_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="UPDATE_LAST_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="COUNT_SUCCESSORS" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="COUNT_PREDECESSORS" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_RECUR_MODIFIED" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TIMESHEET_INOUT_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="COMMENT_COUNT" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_STATUS_STARTED" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_STATUS_COMPLETED" msdata:DateTimeMode="Unspecified" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="POSITION" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_DEPENDENCY_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MARKED" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="READY_TO_START" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TASK_RECURRENCY_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="EXPIRATION_DATE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="STANDBY" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="WEEKEND_ALLOWED_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="NAV_TASK_POSITION" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PERIODICITY_SUMMARY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<dsOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<TASK_ID>5</TASK_ID>
<TASK_NUMBER>1.0000000</TASK_NUMBER>
<TASK_RESUME>Wolf</TASK_RESUME>
<DATE_TASK_MODIFIED>2019-03-29T15:56:29.937</DATE_TASK_MODIFIED>
<IS_ASSIGNED_OR_REVIEWER>0</IS_ASSIGNED_OR_REVIEWER>
<PROJECT_ID>2</PROJECT_ID>
<PROJECT_NUMBER>0000002</PROJECT_NUMBER>
<PROJECT_NAME>Canines</PROJECT_NAME>
<PROJECT_TYPE_NAME>General</PROJECT_TYPE_NAME>
<COMPANY_ID>1</COMPANY_ID>
<TASK_GROUP_ID>4</TASK_GROUP_ID>
<TASK_GROUP_NAME>Development</TASK_GROUP_NAME>
<TASK_GROUP_MYORDER>9999999</TASK_GROUP_MYORDER>
<TASK_TYPE_ID>6</TASK_TYPE_ID>
<TASK_TYPE_NAME>Addition</TASK_TYPE_NAME>
<TASK_TYPE_MYORDER>9999999</TASK_TYPE_MYORDER>
<TASK_STATUS_ID>5</TASK_STATUS_ID>
<TASK_STATUS_NAME>Completed</TASK_STATUS_NAME>
<TASK_STATUS_MYORDER>9999999</TASK_STATUS_MYORDER>
<TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED>1</TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED>
<TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED_LOGICAL_SORT>2</TASK_STATUS_COMPLETED_LOGICAL_SORT>
<TASK_PRIORITY_ID>7</TASK_PRIORITY_ID>
<TASK_PRIORITY_NAME>Normal</TASK_PRIORITY_NAME>
<TASK_PRIORITY_MYORDER>3</TASK_PRIORITY_MYORDER>
<USER_CREATOR_ID>1</USER_CREATOR_ID>
<USERNAME>Dracius</USERNAME>
<FIRST_NAME>Ace</FIRST_NAME>
<LAST_NAME>Rimmer</LAST_NAME>
<TASK_DESC_CREATOR/>
<ESTIMATED_TIME>0.00</ESTIMATED_TIME>
<DATE_EXPECTED_START_TASK>2019-03-29T00:00:00</DATE_EXPECTED_START_TASK>
<DATE_EXPECTED_END_TASK>2019-03-29T00:00:00</DATE_EXPECTED_END_TASK>
<DATE_TASK_CREATED>2019-03-29T13:24:31.82</DATE_TASK_CREATED>
<POURCENTAGE_DONE>10</POURCENTAGE_DONE>
<DOCUMENT_COUNT>0</DOCUMENT_COUNT>
<ACTUAL_START_DATE>2019-03-29T00:00:00</ACTUAL_START_DATE>
<ACTUAL_END_DATE>2019-03-29T00:00:00</ACTUAL_END_DATE>
<DIVIDE_HOURS>true</DIVIDE_HOURS>
<WEEKEND_ALLOWED>0</WEEKEND_ALLOWED>
<UPDATE_USER_ID>3</UPDATE_USER_ID>
<UPDATE_USERNAME>Fenrir</UPDATE_USERNAME>
<COUNT_SUCCESSORS>1</COUNT_SUCCESSORS>
<COUNT_PREDECESSORS>0</COUNT_PREDECESSORS>
<TASK_RECUR_MODIFIED>false</TASK_RECUR_MODIFIED>
<COMMENT_COUNT>0</COMMENT_COUNT>
<DATE_STATUS_STARTED>2019-03-29T19:55:24.24</DATE_STATUS_STARTED>
<DATE_STATUS_COMPLETED>2019-03-29T19:55:24.24</DATE_STATUS_COMPLETED>
<POSITION>325056</POSITION>
<MARKED>0</MARKED>
<READY_TO_START>0</READY_TO_START>
<WEEKEND_ALLOWED_NAME>No</WEEKEND_ALLOWED_NAME>
</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput4" msdata:rowOrder="3" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput5" msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput6" msdata:rowOrder="5" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput7" msdata:rowOrder="6" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput8" msdata:rowOrder="7" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
<dtOutput diffgr:id="dtOutput9" msdata:rowOrder="8" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">...</dtOutput>
</dsOutput>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Example Error Output:

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="dsOutput">
<xs:element name="dsOutput" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="dtAPIErrors">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ErrorNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ErrorDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ErrorType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ParamName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<dsOutput>
<dtAPIErrors diffgr:id="dtAPIErrors1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<ErrorNumber>API0011-009</ErrorNumber>
<ErrorDescription>
Task doesn't exist. It might have been deleted by another user.
</ErrorDescription>
<ErrorType>MSG_FUNCTIONAL</ErrorType>
<Language>en-US</Language>
</dtAPIErrors>
</dsOutput>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat that as xml and use xpath. Here I am reading from file but you would load response into xmldocument. It is really to show you can select by xpath. I am selecting with `SelectSingleNode` but you can see how you could add a loop for `SelectNodes`.

This will only align row wise if nodesets from each xpath are the same length. If not, a shared parent node must be used and then child nodes accessed from that. The row counter would increment within loop over shared parent node.

If using multiple requests, another For Loop would be required over requests and then the next free row should be found at the top of that loop to determine where to start writing to.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Dim node As Object, i As Long, xpath As Variant, j As Long
    j = 1
    For Each xpath In Array("TASK_ID", "TASK_NUMBER", "TASK_RESUME", "TASK_GROUP_NAME")
        ws.Cells(9, j) = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//" & xpath).Text
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

In your case load the function return string. **Edit: updated for multiple nodes**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .LoadXML(GetHTTP(url)) Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Dim node As Object, i As Long, xpath As Variant, j As Long, errorNode As Object, k As Long
    Set errorNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ErrorDescription")
    If Not errorNode Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox errorNode.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If
    j = 1
    For Each xpath In Array("TASK_ID", "TASK_NUMBER", "TASK_RESUME", "TASK_GROUP_NAME")
        k = 0
        For Each node In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//" & xpath)
            ws.Cells(9 + k, j) = node.Text
            k = k + 1
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is only returning the first row, I need it to return all the rows in the array.

Comment: It's also not parsing any errors, such as if I put in an invalid Project ID, I'd like to be able to grab this:
    <dtAPIErrors diffgr:id="dtAPIErrors1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <ErrorNumber>API0011-009</ErrorNumber>
    <ErrorDescription>
    Task doesn't exist. It might have been deleted by another user.
    </ErrorDescription>
    <ErrorType>MSG_FUNCTIONAL</ErrorType>

Comment: See my note about using SelectNodes. I don't see dtAPIErrors in the structure.

Comment: Will the collections of nodes be the same length for each xpath? Would each xpath nodeset continue down the same column?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: The errors are only added to the structure when they exist. I've updated my OP to show an example.

Comment: So, will you have one or the other? Either with error or not with error? And if with error where would you write that?

Comment: It'd only ever be one or the other: If there's an error, only the errors get returned, if there's no error then it returns the original example. I'd want to just output the error to a message window and stop the script.

Comment: You're a saint, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you. Is there anyway to have the message for the error use the ErrorDescription instead of a generic description?